# .htaccess breaking file path for uploads

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, config

I've got a Symfony 2 project and I had to use a .htaccess config to hide the front file and the web directory, but in the process it means I can't access the public uploads folder I created. Is there way I can create a symlink or exception for that route?

Here's my current .htaccess

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^/web/app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/web/app.php - [L]

    # Fix the bundles folder
    RewriteRule ^bundles/(.*)$ /web/bundles/$1  [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # Change below before deploying to production
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/app.php [QSA,L]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't pointing the DocumentRoot to the web dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an exception to not rewrite a certain folder the same way you have disabled rewriting for front controllers. Just add `RewriteRule ^path-to-folder/.* - [L]` to go with them and the files in path-to-folder will be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an exception, like you already did:

```
#disable redirecting for all the files in /web/upload dir
RewriteRule ^web/upload/.* - [L]
```

Put this into the beginning of .htaccess, and it will stop processing before the redirect occurs. One thing, I don't understand, why there is an extra slash at the beginning: `^/web`. Because the first slash should be omitted in .htaccess conditions.